# What is the correct way to make a HTTP request from Angular to Node js API?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular5

Im making an API call rom angular to nodejs like below>

```
        public TUpdation(data): Observable<any>{
          const headers = new HttpHeaders(); 
          headers.set('content-type', null);  
          headers.set('Accept', 'multipart/form-data');
          headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin',"*");
          return this.http.post(API.UPDATION, data, { headers }); 
        }
```

In node.js portion, I'm trying to receive in the function below.

```
      exports.Updation = async (req,res,next) => {
          console.log("req.body : ",req.body); //Not getting the contents (empty)
          var classTM = req.body.checkbox2;
          var _entityclass;
           try{
             if(entityclass){
                _entityclass = "EE";
             }
            else if(entityclass){
                _entityclass = "TM";
             }
            else{
                _entityclass = "TMP";
             }
            try{
               console.log("req.body --- !!!  ",req.body); // Here Im able to get the contents
             }
            catch(e){
              }
           }
       catch(e){
       }
       }
```

My problem here is I can't get the body contents at first. Whatever I'm trying to do, not able to get the re.body contents on top. In second try I'm able to fetch. Can anybody please help me. what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Check whether request send correctly or not with body from Angular side.

Comment: @ireshanpathirana But Im able to get the req.body details in the second try block ..

Comment: Did you end first try catch block correctly?

Comment: @ireshanpathirana yes,

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is an invalid request header. It is meant for response header from the server. You may set it but it is not meaningful

Comment: What are you using for your body parser? Express and Connect by default does not set `req.body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try with this code below:

```
public TUpdation(data): Observable < any > {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    // set content-type: `application/json`
    headers.set('content-type', 'application/json'); 
    // you can comment: multipart/form-data, if it's still does not work
    headers.set('Accept', 'multipart/form-data'); 
    headers.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    // make sure your "data" is not an empty object
    // you can console.log(data); 
    return this.http.post(API.UPDATION, data, {
        headers
    });
}
```

After you change your code in your Angular app with that code above, **now, make sure** You've been add `body-parser` in your express app.

You can set your `body-parser` with this code below:

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

You can copy that code above and put in your `app.js` or `server.js`.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: thanks alot. content type 'application/json' helped me.